# Group dataframe by IDs and list up Articles

Tags: python, dataframe, grouping

I'm facing a problem here and I hope you guys could help me out.
I have the following dataset.

```
Date    cashpointID receiptID   receiptPosID    Article
02.05.2019  cpid01  1   1   A1
02.05.2019  cpid01  1   2   A2
02.05.2019  cpid01  1   3   A3
02.05.2019  cpid02  1   1   A1
02.05.2019  cpid02  1   2   A4
02.05.2019  cpid02  1   3   A5
02.05.2019  cpid02  2   1   A1
02.05.2019  cpid02  2   2   A6
02.05.2019  cpid02  2   3   A6
02.05.2019  cpid02  2   4   A7
02.05.2019  cpid02  2   5   A8
02.05.2019  cpid03  1   1   A2
02.05.2019  cpid03  1   2   A3
02.05.2019  cpid03  1   3   A4
02.05.2019  cpid03  1   4   A5
02.05.2019  cpid03  1   5   A6
```

My goal is pretty simple.
I want every receiptID per cashpointID per Date in one line and all the articles as a list.
Furthermore, if there are duplicate articles in one receiptID, the duplicates can be eliminated.

So, the result should look something like this.

```
Date        cashpointID receiptID   Articles
02.05.2019  cpid01      1       A1 A2 A3
02.05.2019  cpid02      1       A1 A4 A5
02.05.2019  cpid02      2       A1 A6 A7 A8
02.05.2019  cpid03      1       A2 A3 A4 A5 A6
```

I already started with some python-code on my own.
But I'm still pretty new to that topic.
So, I'm interested to see what ideas you guys have.

Thank you so much for your help in advance!!!

Comment: df.groupby(["Date", "cashpointID", "receiptID"], as_index = False).agg({'Articles': '  '.join}) ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hints of Mapotofu and Shaswat I think I've found the answer.
If I do two groupbys in a row like this, it works:

```
data.groupby(["Date", "cashpointID", "receiptID", "Article"], as_index=False).count()

data.groupby(["Date", "cashpointID", "receiptID"], as_index=False).agg({"Articles": ' '.join})
```

If I only did the last groupby (like suggested), the duplicate articles didn't get eliminated. Therefore, I had to do add the first groupby to eliminate the duplicates.